Project issue with pipelines
I'm programming and modifying an application in Python 3 with GTK 3 and gstreamer 1.0 and this is the code I have.
# init Gst and create pipeline
Gst.init(None)
self.player = Gst.Pipeline.new()
self.playbin = Gst.ElementFactory.make("playbin", "player")
self.imagesink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("glimagesink")
self.imagesink.set_property("sync", True)
if self.imagesink:
    self.playbin.set_property("video-sink", self.imagesink)

else:
    self.logger.error("Failed to create GTK sink for video.")
if not self.playbin:
    raise Exception("Failed to create the playbin. Check if GStreamer is installed properly.")

self.playbin.set_property("flags", (1 << 0) | (1 << 1) | (1 << 4))
self.playbin.set_property("current-audio", 0)
self.player.add(self.playbin)

self.logger = logging.Logger("VideoPlayer")
defaultLoggingHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stderr)
self.logger.setLevel(defaultLoggingLevel)
self.logger.addHandler(defaultLoggingHandler)

# Setup audio bin
audiobin = Gst.Bin.new("audio-speed-bin")
self.audiospeedchanger = Gst.ElementFactory.make("pitch", "audiospeedchanger")
if not self.audiospeedchanger:
    self.logger.warning("Pitch element could not be created. Some features may not be available.")
    self.canChangeSpeed = False
else:
    self.canChangeSpeed = True
    audiosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosink")
    #audiosink.set_property("sync", True)
    convert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("audioconvert")

    audiobin.add(self.audiospeedchanger)
    audiobin.add(convert)
    audiobin.add(audiosink)

    # Link elements
    self.audiospeedchanger.link(convert)
    convert.link(audiosink)

    sink_pad = Gst.GhostPad.new("sink", self.audiospeedchanger.get_static_pad("sink"))
    audiobin.add_pad(sink_pad)
    self.playbin.set_property("audio-sink", audiobin)

# Generate DOT file after setting up the pipeline
self.create_pipeline_dot_file("pipeline_setup")

# Connect signals
bus = self.player.get_bus()
bus.add_signal_watch()
bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
bus.connect("message", self.on_message)
bus.connect("sync-message::element", self.on_sync_message)

self.time_format = Gst.Format(Gst.Format.TIME)
self.timeToSeek = -1
self.speed = 1.0
self.nextCallbackTime = -1

But when I run the app, the video is running a couple of times faster and ends before the audio. I have tried different solutions, but still, I have the same issue. I'm generating a dot file and converting it to PNG to analyze the pipelines. I feel I'm kind of stuck, I'm debugging the issue, but still, I couldn't find the solution. Please somebody with more experience than me can give me a route to the solution. I would appreciate it. If you need more details. I will provide them.
I just got confused because I'm not sure if the problem is the timestamp or a bad configuration with the bin.
The program works in this way by loading a subtitle and splitting it into sentences according to the video. You have to type it, trying to guess the whole sentence, but for some reason, I have to press play to execute or run the video.

The code seems to be partial. What is self? See also the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Self is a instance of a class in python.

That's the convention, but how do you define that class, how do you instantiate it, and how do you call this method? Again, please read the links I provided.
